# What defines a frequency in electronics?

Tags: voltage, frequency, wave, graph

As Hertz is defined as one cycle per second, what are the requirements of an electric wave to have a certain frequency? What I mean is more lucid in a picture.[image]

The black wave has a frequency of about 3 Htz and the orange 0.6 Htz, but can the blue wave be defined as 1.5 Htz? How far does the line need to fall each cycle to define a period point?

Comment: look at this question from the standpoint of [Frequency Spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_spectrum) and from the standpoint of [Harmonics](http://www.dspguide.com/ch11/5.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any signal (of any shape) can be the lowest frequency single sinewave imaginable or, a massive concoction of billions of individual sinewaves. What you have drawn (a, b or c) is reproducable (and analysable) as just this - a bunch of sinewaves. If you can draw limits around it where it might repeat then it's realizable mathematically as a series of individual sinewaves (but possible an infinite number in the case of a square wave).

The blue wave will certainly have a 1.5Hz and possibly 3Hz component that is bigger than say a 2Hz or 4Hz component but, because there is a gradual slope upwards it is impossible to say what its lower frequency content will be. It's always easiest to see the lowest component perform one full cycle before being definite about it. For instance the 1.5Hz components may actually dissapear if the full picture was known.

This happens when two sinewaves are multiplied with each other - one component may possibly disappear completely.

Comment: Disappear completely? Or just be of an insignificant relevant amplitude?

Comment: @PhilFrost Disappear is correct: sin(wt)*sin(wt) doesn't have w as frequency component, only DC and 2w.

Answer (score 3):

The amplitude (how far the line "falls" each cycle) or waveshape is irrelevant to the frequency.  The important criterion is that it be a repeating signal.  The frequency in Hz is then how often this repeating pattern occurs in one second.

In some cases the pattern or event might not be regularly repeating.  We can still sometimes use Hz to specify the average occurrance rate of the event, even if individual events aren't predictable.  Depending on the nature of the event or the meaning of the signal, this may or may not be stretching the use of Hz.

For example, the signal from a Giger counter tube is really a series of blips.  The exact time of any one blip is random, but in the aggregate a certain number of blips are expected over some specified time.  It could be acceptable to say that the blip frequency is 35 Hz on average.

You could also be measuring the number of people entering a building.  Each person is a non-repeating blip, but in the aggregate a certain number of people are expected to enter the building over a 1 hour period.  I think that applying Hz to this would be a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

One way to define frequency is to determine the period of a periodic signal.  The frequency is 1/period (in Hz if the period is in seconds).

In another sense, we speak of the "frequency content" of a waveform.  If you imagine that every signal can be represented as a sum of sine waves, where every frequency of sin wave has its own amplitude and time delay, then you'll see that many different kinds of signals can have many different frequencies at the same time.

Your bottom signal, because it has a constant drift is not periodic, and the first definition does not make sense.  Using the "frequency content" definition, though, we would say that the bottom signal has substantial frequency content at 1.5Hz, but it also has some lower and higher frequency components as well.